# Text displayed differently in HTML5

Tags: html, unicode, right-to-left

I am building an HTML5 app that works with iPhone and Android. When I display text in this form:

```
"the number is between 10%-15% 2. the number between 25%-35% 3.the number between 25%-35%...."
```

In Android I see it as entered correctly, but in iPhone I see this

```
"the number is between 10%-15 2.%"
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: How you can expect any1 to help you by just describing your issue but not sharing the relevant code

Comment: The code is not the issue here, i'm just displaying the text below in browser,in <div>,without any smart code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not given us a lot to go on but I would investigate the possibility that the encoding of the text is not compatible with iOS (is the file UTF-8 encoded for example). The other possible issue is that the text you display above is being treated as URL encoded.

Read here:

[UTF-8 vs. Unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643694/utf-8-vs-unicode)

[What are the characters that stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding escapes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8693923/what-are-the-characters-that-stringbyaddingpercentescapesusingencoding-escapes)

Answer (score 0):

Try `the number is between 10%%-15%% 2. the number between 25%%-35%% 3.the number between 25%%-35%%`

Comment: So basically you saying replace `%` with `%%` ?

Comment: Exactly. See if it works. I can't say for sure if it will but it's worth a try.